# Failed to instantiate manager instance. So i tried to set absolute path mtmanapi.dll but how to get all class related this dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, metatrader4

ClrWrapper class working in desktop application so i want to implement P23.MetaTrader4.Manager Clrwrapper class but i getting error

> Failed to instantiate manager instance

So how to set external path dll and get in  WebAPI Project. Please help me thank

Comment: Constructor has second parameter, path to DLL

Comment: "Constructor has second parameter, path to DLL" I am not understand this please describe in detail. Right now i set mtmanapi.dll in IIS Express in program File(x86) its working.

Comment: Same issue come when host web API application on local iis server

Comment: Please provide some code example

Comment: using P23.MetaTrader4.Manager;
namespace ForexMTAPI.Controllers
{
    public class MTAPIController : ApiController
    {
        ClrWrapper main = new ClrWrapper();
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/MTAPI/Login")]
        public int Login(int Login,string Password,string Server)
        {
            int Code = 201;
            main = new ClrWrapper(new P23.MetaTrader4.Manager.Contracts.ConnectionParameters { Login = 4, Password = "abc@123", Server = "107.6.11.11" });
            int conected = main.IsConnected();
        }
    }
}

Comment: After hosting local IIS server also not working. Please help me uriil

Comment: ClrWrapper constructor has second parameter, it's string pointing to mtmanapi.dll, just provide valid path

Comment: Please give me example i am not understand clear. Please edit my code and give me example.

Comment: ClrWrapper main = new ClrWrapper(new P23.MetaTrader4.Manager.Contracts.ConnectionParameters { Login = 4, Password = "abc@123", Server = "107.6.11.11" }, @"D:\Projects\ForexMTAPI\ForexMTAPI\bin\mtmanapi.dll")    --->> after set this its working Uriil thanks a lot

Comment: How to update investor password. Please help me